# Bound on growth of a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, upper-lower-bounds

I have a sequence $a_n$ which satisfies the bound
\begin{equation*} \tag{1}
a_n\ge \frac{a_{n-1}}{2}+c_1\frac{a_{n-2}}{n^{1/4}}-c_2\frac{a_{n-1}^{1/2} a_{n-2}^{1/2}}{n^{1/8}}.
\end{equation*}
Here $c_1,c_2$ are fixed and (strictly) positive numbers, $a_n>0$ for every $n$. I would like to deduce from this a lower bound for $a_n$ in terms of $a_{n-1}$, asymptotically as $n\to\infty$. From rough scaling arguments it seems to me that (1) should be compatible with a behavior of the type
\begin{equation*}
a_n = c \frac{a_{n-1}}{n^{1/4}}
\end{equation*}
for some $c>0$ fixed. Is it possible to prove anything in this direction? Not as an equality of course, but maybe at least something like
\begin{equation*}
a_n \ge c \frac{a_{n-1}}{n^\alpha}
\end{equation*}
for $\alpha$ reasonably close to $1/4$.

Comment: if $$\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{4}\frac{c_2^2}{c_1^2} > 0$$ then we can prove that $a_n \ge c a_{n-1}$ when $n\to+\infty$

Comment: You mean using positivity to throw away pieces, right? You are right, I'm sorry. I forgot to say that there is no control on how large $c_2$ is compared to $c_1$.